# File Transfer Problems

Tags: hardware

Ihave two raspberry PI's one is a B+ and the other is a model 2. My problem is this with the B+ connected I can move files from my windows computer to the PI with no trouble but when I connect the model 2 I can no longer transfer files
my windows pc tell me I don't have authorization or privilege to do that. My B+ is running raspbmc and the model 2 is running Xbian when the model 2 is connected I can see all the files I just can't do anything with them.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The user you are logged into on your model 2 doesn't have permissions on the files you see. Check which user owns them, and if they have read/write access.
You can change this by logging on with the user that does have access to them and using chmod or chown (Or GUI equivalent settings)

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try `who` to see who is logged in and then run `ls -l` within the directory which the files you want to transfer are located. If the permissions differ, then try `sudo chmod "the_permissions_needed"` to get the right clearance for your logged in user.